# How can I use Django remove the whitespaces between tags and text?

Tags: python, django

I use Django and I want remove the whitespaces after or before that block.

I found the **spaceless** in [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless)
But it just only space between tags is removed, not space between tags and text.

Use [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/)

```
{% for item in seq -%}
{{ item }}
{%- endfor %}
```

it's remove the whitespaces after or before that block.

How can I use this function in Django?

Comment: Have you seen the `trimmed` option for [`blocktrans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag)?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it is impossible in django templates.  If this is a HTML template then you can use this dirty hack:

```
{% for item in seq %}<!--
-->{{ item }}<!--
-->{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks your answer,but when I use like{% block title %}<!--
-->something<!--
-->{% endblock %},it's <title><!-- -->something<!-- --></title>, It isn't perfect